# Logitech G502 lightspeed adapter disconnects after disk migration on Debian 12

Tags: linux, usb, ssd, debian, migration

Recently I treated myself to a 1TB NVMe SSD to replace my very old Samsung 750 500Gb SSD.

I cloned my debian 12 install to the new disk using clonezilla's disk-to-disk, expand partition setting. apart from what I'm about to describe, the system works very well and the full disk is available on my main partition. I know that it is running fully on the NMVe drive because I have now removed the old SSD from my system.

I own a Logitech g502 lightspeed mouse that I bought new about 2 years ago. It has been serving me very well until I did the disk migration and in fact continues to serve me well on both another machine AND the same machine on windows (dual boot to another disk that didn't get migrated), but since the disk migration, the wireless adapter has stopped working intermittently on linux.

Symptoms are as follow:

- If I plug in the wireless adapter after bootup, it will not work.
- If I boot the system with the adapter plugged in, it will work, but will randomly stop working even if i am actively using the mouse. after it stops working, I did not yet have success in making it work again without a reboot
- If I plug in the mouse using its microUSB cable, it will work fine. I know that this mouse gives priority to the cable, so plugging in the wireless adapter does nothing.

Here are some logs from dmesg that I captured when I plugged in the adapter until it looked like it was done outputting things: https://pastebin.com/fy9eEYza

Here are some logs from dmesg that I captured when I plugged in the cable: https://pastebin.com/VF2VGmN9

Both the adapter and the cable are on usb 3.0 ports, and the behavior is the same regardless of what port I use. I am struggling to explain why the disk migration would break this specifically, but it worked yesterday and today it doesn't and that's what changed. All other USB devices (my headset and my keyboard) work without issue.

All my software is up to date, running debian 12 on kernel 5.10.0-21-amd64.

any help as to why this disk migration would cause this (or if it is in fact a complete coincidence)?

Answer (score -1):

For what it's worth, i have found the problem.

Posting the answer here for future reference and to not leave eventual people who searched all of Google without an answer.

---

**In short**:

Unplug your VR headset.

**In long**:

I own a VR headset (specifically Valve Index) and linux support for VR in general is not very good (this is the entire reason I have the other windows drive laying around in my PC). my headset used to be plugged in a USB port that didn't cause problems, but during the SSD upgrade I apparently plugged it in a different port, and that was the root cause.

I discovered this after throwing in the towel and using my mouse plugged with a cable, i started playing a game using a bluetooth controller, and that did a similar thing to the problem i described above where the bluetooth adapter basically just stopped working. however, this time, `dmesg` was actually helpful and told me about a different USB port, which as you can guess i finally identified as the port the VR headset that i completely forgot about was plugged in. after unplugging it and rebooting, my bluetooth adapter and my mouse adapter both work fine.

I think this is due to which ports are direct to the CPU vs. which ports are going through the chipset. I haven't identified which is which (and i don't care to) but there is at least one USB port on the back of my motherboard for which this issue doesn't exist.